# Signature of quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Give is the quadratic form:

$q(x,y,z,t) = x^2 + (4 + λ)y^2 + (1 + 4λ)z^2 + λt^2 + 4xy + 2xz + 4(1 − λ)yz + 2λyt + (1 − 4λ)zt $

I should compute the signature of $q$.

I load it into a matrix:

$q(x,y,z,t) =\begin{bmatrix} x&y&z&t \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&1&0\\2&4+\lambda&2(1-\lambda)& \lambda\\1&2(1-\lambda)&1+4\lambda&1/2(1-4\lambda)\\0&\lambda&1/2(1-4\lambda)&\lambda \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\\t \end{bmatrix}$

Now I'm stuck.

How do I move on from here? Simplifying is a mess, is there another way?

Comment: Try to collect the squares, for example $(x+2y)^2=x^2+4xy+4y^2$ and the terms $x^2,4xy,4y^2$ actually appear in the quadratic form.

Comment: @Peter I've encountered serious difficulties collecting the squares, that's why I put it into a matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can write

\begin{equation}
q(x,y,z,t) = (x+2y+z)^2 + \frac{1}{4}(z+t)^2 - \frac{1}{4}(z-t)^2 + \lambda (y-2z+t)^2
\end{equation}

The answer should follow immediately from this.

Comment: the question is ... how did you do it?

Comment: Just separate the $\lambda$-dependent terms from the $\lambda$-independent ones, and then try to write each part as sums and differences of squares. After you notice the big squares -- the ones with three terms, the rest is straightforward.

Comment: I got to $q= \lambda((y-2z)^2 + t^2 + 2yt - 4zt) + (x-2y)^2 + z^2 + 2xz + 4yz + zt$     How do I go on from here? excuse me for the question btw.

Comment: Rather than pair them up like this, make use directly of the formula $(a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ac$, it should be easier.

Comment: And btw, in your formula there is a little sign error: $x-2y$ should really be $x+2y$.

Answer (score 0):

Diagonalizing the matrix isn’t all that much of a mess.

Going down the first column, subtract twice the first row/column from the second, and subtract the first row/column from the third: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0 \\ 0&\lambda&-2\lambda&\lambda \\ 0&-2\lambda&4\lambda&\frac12(1-4\lambda) \\ 0&\lambda&\frac12(1-4\lambda)&\lambda\end{bmatrix}.$$ Moving down the next column, add two times row/column two to three and subtract it from the last one: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0 \\ 0&\lambda&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&\frac12 \\ 0&0&\frac12&0\end{bmatrix}.$$ You have to be a bit careful with the last two rows/columns, since you can’t just swap them as you might when performing Gaussian elimination. Instead, you need to add the fourth row/column to the third to create a non-zero diagonal entry and then proceed as before. After a few more operations you end up with $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0 \\ 0&\lambda&0&0 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&0&-\frac14\end{bmatrix}.$$ If you also want the basis that diagonalizes this matrix, apply the same *row*, but not *column*, operations to the identity matrix.